# shaswat@ubuntults:~/Desktop$ , need to know about the symbols here?

Tags: 14.04, command-line

What exactly they mean( ~ and $ ),these are the code which we see on the terminal , so could anyone tell me the meaning of these symbols , are they having any particular meaning of there existence there or not.

Comment: Why did you edit back corrections to your spelling and grammar? "Their" is correct where Zanna put it.

Answer (score 11):

The tilde `~` is a shortcut for your home. This part of the prompt is the current working directory, which, when you open a terminal, is `/home/USERNAME`. It changes when you move around

```
zanna@monster:~$ cd playground/cake
zanna@monster:~/playground/cake$ cd /etc
zanna@monster:/etc$ cd
zanna@monster:/etc$ cd ~/Desktop
zanna@monster:~/Desktop$
```

The full path for `~/playground/cake` is `/home/zanna/playground/cake` but the prompt shows the short version. I move to `/etc`and the prompt shows the full path no `~` Then I use the `~` in a command to move to my `Desktop`, which saves some typing as well as space in the prompt.

the `$` means you are a normal user, not root - it changes to a `#` if you open a root shell:

```
zanna@monster:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for zanna: 
root@monster:~#
```

Comment: `~playground/cake` is more likely `/home/playground/cake`. Being precise `~playground` refers to the home directory of user `playground`. I guess you miss a slash sign.